# Setting a table to display: block

Tags: css, width, css-tables

I like to get my table behave like a block element. I cannot set it to width:100% because it does have some padding, this is going to result 100% + the paddings PX.

Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/LScqQ

Finally the table does what I want, can you see the box-shadow? But the table children don't like it that way^^

I guess the TH inside the THEAD are the problem.
They do not get the aspected ratio of 66% to 33%.

Help wanted...

Comment: This is not a blog or forum. If you have to update your question with new information, clearly mention it. New readers do not have the knowledge of your pre-edit question.

Comment: Please comment or reply if the answer wasn't what you wanted, else accept it to close the question (by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer). Welcome to SO, and hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found the answer by myself.

Put your table inside a wrapper container and write a CSS rule similar to this:

**//HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper-table">
<table>...</table>
</div>
```

**//CSS**

```
.wrapper-table > table
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now the table will no longer overflow your layout and fits perfectly like most elements do.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Why didn't I think of this before?? :)

Answer (score 9):

Your table should be `display: table`. If you're worried about the sizing, use `box-sizing: content-box`.

The reason is that `display: table` creates the table layout mechanism the rows and columns need to be laid out; in certain conditions if the required elements aren't there, they will be implicitly created, but it can cause problems. (You can test that out by making a table layout with `div`s and setting them to `display: table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`, which are the default user agent styles for `table`, `tr`, and `td` elements. If you play around with unsetting the styles on the divs in different combinations, you'll see that sometimes the browser implicitly makes the table layout incorrectly.)

So, always leave the `display: table-*` styles intact if you want an actual table layout. Sort out your width issues using the appropriate styles for that. If you describe better what you want, maybe you can get a better answer.