# Scrollable table with automatic column widths

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to make a table with a scrollable `<tbody>` and a fixed `<thead>`.

I have attempted to do so here https://jsfiddle.net/ghnfzwm6/11/. However, as you can see the `<thead>` is not lined up with the `<tbody>`. Also, the scroll wheel is all the way to the right whereas I would like it right next to the table.

Does anyone know how I can fix this without setting fixed widths for the columns?

**EDIT:** Additionally, `top: 0;` moves the `<thead>` to the top of my page which is ok on the fiddle but not normally. However, without it there is a small gap...

**EDIT2:** I have found this solution https://jsfiddle.net/uo5v0cfw/11/. However, the problem gere is that the furthest right column is cut off by the scroll bar. This can be fixed by changing the `overflow-x` to `auto`, but I don't want to have to scroll horizontally...

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting the `thead` to be `position: sticky;` instead of `fixed`. When an element is set to have a position of `fixed` or `absolute` the browser does not render it as part of its normal containing block. Because your `thead` is positioned as `fixed` it isn't being rendered as part of that containing block and thus your `tbody` is collapsing down to the size of its content. Using `sticky` will avoid this because it is designed to keep the element as part of the original containing block while allowing it to stick to the page in your determined location.

Just be sure to check browser support and polyfill if needed:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Answer (score 1):

Css for the #content div is not required. This css is enough for your scrollable table. I added some comments in the css below.

update: added minimum css for mobile support

```
#content {
}
#tasks-table-wrapper {
  width: 800px; /* or use % for the width */
  height: 546px;
  max-height: 546px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* only Y axis scroll */
}
#tasks-table-wrapper * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* keep content in a TD cell */
}
#tasks {
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  font-size: 0;
}
#tasks, #tasks thead, #tasks tbody, #tasks tr {
  width: 100%; /* keep all elements full width */
}
#tasks th, #tasks td {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #121212;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#tasks th {
  position: sticky; /* keep TH on top */
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
#tasks td {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* minimum for mobile support */
@media (max-width: 767.9px) {
  #tasks-table-wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  #tasks {
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  }
}
```

Comment: Added a minimum css for mobile support. Tables and mobiles don't like eachother but some css is possible ;-)

Comment: Thank you. This is a very close to a solution. However, my table is centred like this https://jsfiddle.net/ghnfzwm6/15/. Would you know how to move the scrollbar just to the right of it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this... add `position:relative;` to #tasks-table-wrapper.

**CSS code**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper {
    height: 546px;
    max-height: 546px;
    width: 35%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks {
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #121212;
    font-size: 0;

}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks thead {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #121212;
  text-align: left;

}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks th {
  padding: 20px;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks tbody {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #bbb;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 57px;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks tbody tr td {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="tasks-table-wrapper">
    <table id="tasks">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If you need to preserve the table display properties then you can do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/joseluismurillorios/0tk3z587/12/):

Add position sticky to your th elements:

```css
#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks th {
  padding: 20px;

  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
}
```

And remove the fixed property from your thead element

```css
#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks thead {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #121212;
  text-align: left;
  /* position: fixed; */
  /* top: 0; */
}
```

You may also change the table width to 100% and the wrapper to the desired size:

```css
#tasks-table-wrapper {
  height: 546px;
  max-height: 546px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #121212;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you don't care about table css properties, change the table elements display property to block or flex, I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joseluismurillorios/rc38kad7/2/) and a [pen](https://codepen.io/joseluismurillorios/pen/KKwxwZV), hope it helps.

Comment: I'd avoid changing display properties of table rows when possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456216/5253011

Answer (score -1):

Try this.
Position `sticky` in TH (it's better for cross-browser)and `border-collapse: collapse;` in TABLE.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper {
  height: 546px;
  max-height: 546px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #121212;
  font-size: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks thead {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #121212;
  text-align: left;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks thead tr {

}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks th {
  padding: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks tbody {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #bbb;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 57px;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks tbody tr {

}

#tasks-table-wrapper table#tasks tbody tr td {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="tasks-table-wrapper">
    <table id="tasks">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
        <tr>
          <td>AAA</td>
          <td>BBB</td>
          <td>CCC</td>
          <td>DDD</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @bron for providing a jsfiddle with an almost complete solution. The last piece was to make the scrollbar go next to the table which I have done here https://jsfiddle.net/ghnfzwm6/16/.

```
#content {
  ...
  text-align: center;
}

#tasks-table-wrapper {
  width: auto;
  ...
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And removed

```
#tasks, #tasks thead, #tasks tbody, #tasks tr {
  width: 100%;
}
```